# Was Dumbledore originally planned to be a villain?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

Someone in a private discussion recently mentioned that they recall information that Rowling originally planned Dumbledore to be an actual villain *(let's leave aside the quibble that a ton of fans consider him a villain regardless of JKR's official stance that he's a hero, even supposedly second most favorite after Harry).*

I tried searching for any mentions of such info, and haven't found anything beyond fan theories, nothing tracing to JKR's original plans or interviews.

**Is there any *canonical* information that would confirm that Dumbledore character was originally planned to be a villain?**

Comment: A rare DVK sighting.

Comment: Nothing useful in the early draft stuff released by JKR on her old website; https://www.hp-lexicon.org/source/other-canon/jkr/jkr-com-scrapbook/

Comment: @Valorum - heh I'm just using the site as theoretically intended, when and only when I need an answer to a question in my practical life. Well, or at least to win an internet argument :P

Comment: *There is no good and evil, there is only power, and those too weak to seek it.*